# Pinvoke "System.AccessViolationException" when trying to import unmanaged dll

Tags: c#, c

I am trying to import a driver dll for a piece of equipment my company uses, but I can't seem to get this to work. I am new to c# so please go easy on me. This is related to a post I made yesterday, I am attempting to convert a C program over to C#.

I wrote this code so that I could start to understand PInvoke

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace PInvokeTest {
  class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        Int32 session_handle = 0;
        Byte state_buffer = 0;
        Int16 result = 1, PortNum = 1, PortType = 1;

        session_handle = TMExtendedStartSession(PortNum, PortType);

        result = TMSearch(session_handle, state_buffer, 1, 1, 0xEC);

        if (result == 1)
            Console.WriteLine("Device Found");

        if (result == -201)
            Console.WriteLine("Hardware Driver Not Found");

        else
            Console.WriteLine("Network Error");



        Console.ReadKey();
    }
    [DllImport("IBFS32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    public static extern Int32 TMExtendedStartSession(Int16 PortNum, Int16 PortType);

    [DllImport("IBFS32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    public static extern Int16 TMSearch(Int32 session_handle, Byte state_buffer, int p1, int p2, int p3);  

  }
}
```

I am trying to use these 2 functions

TMExthendedStartSession http://files.maximintegrated.com/sia_bu/licensed/docs/1-wire_sdk_win/TMEX/exst8l9q.html

and TMSearch
http://files.maximintegrated.com/sia_bu/licensed/docs/1-wire_sdk_win/TMEX/sear1ezy.html

When I run TMExthendedStartSession I get System.AccessViolationException, but when I run TMSearch alone I get a message 
"*Managed Debugging Assistant 'PInvokeStackImbalance' has detected a problem in 'C:\PInvokeTest\Debug\PInvokeTest.vshost.exe'*."

The function TMSearch does return a value of -201 though.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: A are you sure the calling convention is `Cdecl`?

Comment: According to the documentation you link to those APIs use the Pascal calling convention, not cdecl.

Comment: Ah... How was I able to get TMSearch to return a valid error code when calling with C though?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In 32 bit Windows, the pascal calling convention maps to stdcall. There is a `#define` near the top of `WinDef.h` (or `minwindef.h` in more modern SDKs) that maps `pascal` to `__stdcall`.

On top of that, your parameters are all wrong. It should be like this:

```
[DllImport("IBFS32.dll")]
public static extern int TMExtendedStartSession(
    short PortNum, 
    short PortType,
    IntPtr EnhancedOptions 
);

[DllImport("IBFS32.dll")]
public static extern short TMSearch(
    int session_handle, 
    IntPtr state_buffer, 
    short p1, 
    short p2, 
    short p3
);
```

The `state_buffer` parameter might perhaps be better declared as `byte[]`. It's hard to tell from here what the semantics are.

Comment: It's actually explicitly called out in the headers that pascal maps to `__stdcall` however I couldn't find where they had moved that define in the latest headers with a cursory search.

Comment: @Mgetz Thanks. It took me a while to dig it out. It's near the top of WinDef.h

Comment: Appears to have been moved to `minwindef.h` in the 8.1 sdk

Comment: After switching to StdCall, I no longer get the -201 value returned from TMSearch.

Comment: The missing parameters and wrongly typed parameters are just as important to fix

Comment: Anyway, are you still stuck? Do you need more in this question?

Comment: Ok, I found that there is a 64bit dll, so I am using that now. Is there any way I can write this without using "unsafe" code? I got it to build and TMExtenededStartSession is giving me a value when I use an int* for EnhancedOptions to pass null. How would I use IntPtr here?

Comment: Very hard for me to say with the information you have presented so far. Very unlikely that you would need unsafe. I thought I answered the question that you asked. Did I not do that?

Comment: I see, I used IntPtr.Zero for EnhancedOptions and it builds without unsafe. I need to add more functions from this API, so I am sure that I will run into more issues, I'll probably be back soon. Thank you for getting me started in the right direction!

Comment: If this is the answer to the question, perhaps you might accept it. I'm offering this advice since you are new and perhaps do not know these customs yet.

Comment: Would you suggest another method for this? Also, any ideas on how I could implement this function without unsafe? http://files.maximintegrated.com/sia_bu/licensed/docs/1-wire_sdk_win/TMEX/rdef16b2.html

Comment: You don't need unsafe for that. Those two parameters are both `out short`. I honestly believe that I answered the question that you asked. These extra questions in the comments are new questions.

Comment: The point is that C only has pass-by-value. So any references need to be implemented by passing an address, hence the use of pointers. But in C# there are no pointers (outside of unsafe), and the equivalent to a parameter of type `int*` used to return a value is `out int`.

Comment: Oh yes, sorry about that. I marked it as the answer. Thanks again!